# Use Jackson to parse JSON nodes inside a JSON node

Tags: java, json, jackson

So I'm new to the Jackson library and am trying to parse a node in a JSON file which has other nodes inside of it, so for example, it would look like this:

```
{ "node1": "value1",
  "node2": "value2",
  "node3": {
           "innerNode1": "value1",
           "innerNode2": "value2"
           }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is have the entire node defined inside of a class, but then have node3 be it's own separate class which acts just like a regular Java Object parsed with Jackson, so it has all the same setter and getter methods. So I would like to be able to do something like call `masterNode.getNode1` and have it output `value1`, but also be able to call `node3.getInnerNode1` and have it output `value1`

I'm not sure how something like this would be done, any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Here is the code I'm using:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ContactInfo[] result) {
        int length = result.length;
        ArrayList<ContactInfo> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<PhoneNumber> numberMap = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
        ArrayList<String> workNumber = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            contacts.add(result[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            names.add(contacts.get(i).getName());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            numberMap.add(contacts.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
        }

        for(PhoneNumber num: numberMap) {
            workNumber.add(num.getWork());
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(local, R.layout.list_item, R.id.contactName, workNumber);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

As far as everything goes, nothing breaks down until I get to trying to get the actual number out of the PhoneNumber class, that's where it gives me a NullPointerError. I have the classes setup, however they are quite long as there are a lot of fields, but I have tested this code and it is grabbing things correctly, and all of that, the breakdown is when trying to grab things out of the PhoneNumber class (i.e. the "work" number.)

Edit: ContactInfo class:

```
package com.example.codingchallenge;

import java.util.Map;

public class ContactInfo {
private String name, company, detailsURL, smallImageURL;
private int employeeId, birthdate;
private PhoneNumber phone;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getDetailsURL() {
    return detailsURL;
}

public void setDetailsURL(String detailsURL) {
    this.detailsURL = detailsURL;
}

public String getSmallImageURL() {
    return smallImageURL;
}

public void setSmallImageURL(String smallImageURL) {
    this.smallImageURL = smallImageURL;
}

public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}

public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}

public int getBirthdate() {
    return birthdate;
}

public void setBirthdate(int birthdate) {
    this.birthdate = birthdate;
}

public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}

Comment: Just create nested Pojos. The root of the JSON is your root Pojo which has a dependency on a `node3` pojo.

Comment: If the properties aren't lining up, you may need a [PropertyNamingStrategy](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/PropertyNamingStrategy.html).

Comment: It's not that their not lining up I don't think, it's that it isn't recognizing that something like node3 has it's own class that gets attributed to it, so I can't access values like innerNode1.

Comment: I recently answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22212300/600137

Comment: Show us your attempt. This maps extremely well to a `RootNode` with 2 `String` fields, `node1` and `node2` and a third `NestedNode` field named `node3`. The `NestedNode` class would have two `String` fields `innerNode1` and `innerNode2`.

Comment: Can you go over the `RootNode`, my attempt was exactly like that, I used an ObjectMapper, and I had fields for every object I needed, and when I got to the Node with nodes inside of it, tried mapping that into an object of that type, an it didn't work. Would you use something other than an ObjectMapper to do that?

Comment: No - objectMapper is fine. What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: I keep getting a NullPointerError, hold on, I'm gonna edit my first post with my code that I'm trying to use to get it to print out the things I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
public static class ContactInfo {
    private String name;
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}

public static class PhoneNumber {
    private String work;

    public String getWork() {
        return work;
    }

    public void setWork(String work) {
        this.work = work;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    // POJO
    ContactInfo info1 = new ContactInfo();
    info1.setName("Neel1");
    PhoneNumber num = new PhoneNumber();
    num.setWork("123 456 7890");
    info1.setPhoneNumber(num);

    String json = new ObjectMapper().defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(info1);
    System.out.println(json);

    // From JSON
    String info2Json = "{ \"name\" : \"Neel2\", \"phoneNumber\" : { \"work\" : \"098 765 4321\" } }";
    ContactInfo info2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(info2Json, ContactInfo.class);

    doSomething(new ContactInfo[] { info1, info2 });
}

private static void doSomething(ContactInfo[] result) {
    for(ContactInfo each : result) {
        String name = each.getName();
        String workPhone = each.getPhoneNumber().getWork();
        doSomething(name, workPhone);
    }

}

private static void doSomething(String name, String workPhone) {
    System.out.println("name: " + name + ", work: " + workPhone);
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "name" : "Neel1",
  "phoneNumber" : {
    "work" : "123 456 7890"
  }
}
name: Neel1, work: 123 456 7890
name: Neel2, work: 098 765 4321
```

Comment: Check code above, my class setup is exactly like yours, I am trying to grab the items out not write them, but I think the class setup should be pretty much the same.

Comment: IS it possible that num.getWork() returns null?

Comment: No, I just checked all of those again, as I used Eclipse to auto-generate my getters and setters since there's quite a few. But it does return the field "work" which should be mapped to the work number. So my guess it is never actually going in and setting those variables to equal anything.

Comment: Could you post the ContactInfo class that you have?

Comment: Just posted it up, it's long but as I said, I don't see any issues with it that should be giving me a problem.

Comment: See if the updated example helps you read / write from / to JSON as you need. I think the best approach is to make sure your POJOs resemble the JSON as much as possible (avoid using a Map unless you are bound to).

Comment: Oh boy.... OK, so I made an absolutely stupid mistake. The name in the JSON file is "phone"... not PhoneNumber. So yeah, that's why nothing was working, once I made that simple fix it worked like a charm.